# Delete Node isn't working with Simple XML (PHP)

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I want to delete a node if the title of an node is matching a filter (array). I use `unset()` and I already tried `$node` and `$item` but both arguments won't delete my node...

What is wrong in this code? - I do enter the if condition, because I see `in if` in my console!

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load("shop1.xml");
$pathXML = "/products/product";
$titleArray = array("Test", "Battlefield 1");


$doc = simplexml_import_dom($dom);

$items = $doc->xpath($pathXML);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $node = dom_import_simplexml($item);
    $title = $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
    echo $title . "\n";

    foreach ($titleArray as $titles) {
        echo $titles . "\n";
        if (mb_stripos($title, $titles) !== false) {
            echo "in if\n\n";
            unset($item);
        }
    }
}

$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save("shop1_2.xml");
```

XML File:

```
<products>
<product>
    <title>Battlefield 1</title>
    <url>https://www.google.de/</url>
    <price>0.80</price>
</product>
<product>
    <title>Battlefield 2</title>
    <url>https://www.google.de/</url>
    <price>180</price>
</product>
</products>
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're doing is unsetting a local variable. Instead you need to alter the DOM:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->load("shop1.xml");
$xpathQuery = "/products/product";
$titleArray = array("Test", "Battlefield 1");
$xp = new DomXpath($dom);
$items = $xp->query($xpathQuery);
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $title = $item->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->textContent;
    echo "$title\n";
    if (in_array($title, $titleArray)) {
        $item->parentNode->removeChild($item);
    }
}
$dom->saveXML();
$dom->save("shop1_2.xml");
```

Comment: It is working! - Thanks! But I have one question left. Is it possible to use mb_stripos() instand of in_array()? I know, in_array() is faster, but I can not say "ignore multibyte case". Or is there a way to use in_array() with "ignore multibyte case"?

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't use the multi byte function in there instead.

Comment: But the multibyte function is not case insensitive!